# How to save & retrieve videoview state when orientation is changed in android

Tags: orientation, android-videoview

I want to change the size of video if I change the orientation mode (from portrait to landscape).

If I change the size of the video, the activity is re-created so the video is reloaded, instead of resuming (from where it was changed, so that it just starts from there only.)

I have used the `onConfigurationChanged` method, when mode is changed whole activity is rotated. I want to just full screen the video.

Another approach that I tried is: `onSaveInstanceState` method, but how to save & retrieve videoview object in bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a service to play your media files.  When you change orientation of the device  it creates the  activity again.

Comment: How would you use this in the context of a VideoView? The VideoView has a UI (naturally).